# EF Core Filter results based on child data

Tags: entity-framework

Given tables CatalogItem and Option
Where CatalogItem has 0..many Option

In SQL I can do this...

```
Select * from
    CatalogItem C
    inner join [Option] O on O.CatalogItemId = C.Id 
Where
    O.Quantity > 0
```

So simple.  In EF I have entities

```
public class CatalogItem 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Option
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int CatalogItem Id { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

In EF I've tried

```
var q = context.CatelogItems
   .Include(i => i.Options)
   .Where(i => i.Options.Any(o => o.Quantity > 0)).ToList();
```

And various other things, but so far I am not able to get the equivalent results as I am from the above SQL.  Namely, all catalog items that have at least one option that had a quantity > 0

I've seen some other posts looking for the same with a join, with a projection that includes both sets of objects as an anonymous type, etc.  but I'm looking for a List that has the Options collection populated IF there are options with a quantity... all in one DB query.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
var q=from c in context.catalogItem
      join o in context.options on c.id equal o.CatalogItemId
where o.quantity>0
```

But I think you need to use `Group by` as below:

```
 var cQuery=from c in context.catalogItem select c;

 var oQuery=from o in context.options 
        group o by new {o.CatalogItemId}into groups
        select new {CatalogItemId=groups.Key.Id,TQuantity=groups.Sum(t => t.Quantity)};

 var q=from c in cQuery
    join o in oQuery on c.id=o.CatalogItemId
    where o.TQuantity>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party package to use [`IncludeFilter`](https://entityframework-plus.net/download)

[**Query IncludeFilter**](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-include-filter)

```cs
var q = context.CatelogItems
   .IncludeFilter(i => i.Options.Where(o => o.Quantity > 0))
   .ToList();
```